# Default file system on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, filesystem, ext4, default

Why does ubuntu 12.10 default to ext2 file system? Is ext4 not stable enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it does indeed default to ext4. Ubuntu has used ext4 as the default for quite some time now.

If you're having filesystems mounted as ext2, there was likely a problem with the installation, or perhaps a problem with your hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know the reason why it defaulted to ext2. I deleted all partitions and retried. Shows ext4 now.

Comment: gparted uses ext2 as default value.
if you're too quick to press OK, 
you will end up with an ext2 partition.